# Mod-16 counter design

Tags: for-loop, verilog, counter, hdl

```
module counter_16 (
    input clk,
    input reset,      // Synchronous active-high reset
    output reg [3:0] q);
    integer i;
    
    always @(posedge clk)
        begin
            q<=0;
            if (reset)
                q <= 4'd0;
            else 
                 for (i=0; i<16; i=i+1)
                    begin
                        q <= q+1;
                    end
        end
endmodule
```

I was trying to make a mod16 counter. This code is working fine. But, at every clock, should the output become 15?  Please explain the working of a `for` loop in this `always` block.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a 4-bit counter, this is the customary way to code it:

```
always @(posedge clk)
    begin
        if (reset)
            q <= 4'd0;
        else 
            q <= q+1;
    end
```

Your code has multiple nonblocking assignments (using `<=`), which is not a good coding practice.  There is no need for a `for` loop.

> should the output become 16?

Since you declared `q` as 4 bits wide, it will take on the values 0 to 15.  It can not have the value 16; that would require at least 5 bits.

Comment: Thankyou!  I realized that I mistakenly wrote it as 16. It should be 15. Eventually I wrote the same code that you gave as a solution. But I am not able to understand the working of a for loop in the always block in the above mentioned code.  Once a positive edge of clock occurs isn't the whole for loop is supposed to run at once?  And if the above statement is true then after every clock the value of q should be 15. but what I see in the waveform is that "i" is always 16, but the "q" is incrementing at every clock till 15 and again getting iterated(as Expected).